# Using SAP Ariba Open API's, is it possible to export a Supplier's Qualification Questionnaire into RSA Archer?

Tags: rsa-archer-grc, sap-ariba

Summary: I am a buyer who wants to integrate SAP Ariba with Archer using the SAP Ariba Open API's. During the Supplier Lifecycle & Performance Management process, my potential suppliers fill out a questionnaire to meet the Supplier Qualification step. I would like to automate the export of this completed questionnaire.

Things I've tried: Attempted to access API documentation but it is locked behind a paywall
Contacted support and learned this can be done manually by exporting the completed questionnaire into a CSV.

Ideally: the Ariba Open API's allow me to export the supplier's completed questionnaire and import into Archer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SAP products, as for RSA ARCHER you can register with RSA Archer Community portal and download Archer API documentation with API samples. You can register there as long as you have access to Archer license key. You can get it on the server where your Archer instance is running from Archer Control Panel.
Assuming you can extract data from SAP in CSV/TXT/XML format, then you can use either Archer data feed or Archer API to create/update records in Archer.

I hope someone will help you with SAP. Documentation for Archer API is accessible from RSA. Ask you Archer admin for license key and you can get it.

Good luck!